# Get phone from User Flow in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I've set up a user flow in Azure AD B2C that uses the Phone/Email signup Identity provider.
The process works so far, but I want to get the phone number that is used to log in to store it in my application's user profile.
I plan to use the number for messaging at a later stage.

I've been looking around for hours and couldn't find any way to get it as a claim.

Is there any waty to retrieve the value, like getting it from the B2C AD with a separate request in the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the phone number is collected for multi-factor authentication, You cannot read it using graph API or as a claim while using built-in user flows.

If you were to switch to custom policies, You can modify the policies to return it as a claim in your JWT token, write to it a custom attribute or use an API call to persist it somewhere else.

With custom policies, you still won't be able to read the phone number using Graph API as long as you are using the default claim. You would need to make some modifications to starter policies to save it to a custom attribute or mobile claim so that you can access it using graph API. You would also need to ensure that the extra claim is in sync with the default claim.

**Note**: If you use the phone signup sign in as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/phone-authentication-user-flows) in the docs for user flows, you will be able to get the user's number with a graph call. It's explained in the same documentation.

Example
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{object_id}?$select=identities`

```json
"identities": [
        {
            "signInType": "phoneNumber",
            "issuer": "contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
            "issuerAssignedId": "+11231231234"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: I have indeed set up the phone signin as in the article. Seems Like I have to make a graph call after all then.